# @null in a custom view

Tags: android, android-custom-view

I am trying to make a custom view that will accept `@null` on some property

```
 <declare-styleable name="CustomButton">
    <attr name="icon" format="reference"/>
</declare-styleable>
```

I want this parameter to accept `@null`

when I read it in the attrs, how do i find out that `@null` was entered as opposed to this property not set at all ?

```
<CustomButton 
  .... 
  app:icon="@null"
/>

        val icon = ta.getDrawable(R.styleable.CustomButton_icon)
           what comes here?
```

Comment: Why do you want to pass null just don't specify app:icon, then  instead of getDrawable use getResourceId and pass -1 as default parameter and make your required changes.

Comment: there is some default behaviour, i want to override that with the @null

Answer (score 1):

So I did my research and I found these points usefull and made my conclusion. It might help you.

First things first if you have some custom attribute, in this case, `icon` when you specify some drawable reference to it i.e actually existing drawable reference for example

```
app:icon = "@drawable/some_drawable_that_does_exist"
```

the `getDrawable()` returns the corresponding drawable mentioned.

Point 1: What if you don't mention icon in XML? (You are not writing `@null` here)

> Well In that case the getDrawable() will simply return null as drawable

Point 2: What if you mention icon as `@null` in XML?

> Well in this case also the getDrawble() will simply return null as the drawable

As I said earlier you can just use a simple check before doing your operations like this

```
val icon : Drawable? = ta.getDrawable(R.styleable.CustomButton_icon)
```

Note the type is Drawable? i.e `nullable` even if you don't mention it explicitly it stills  give you a `nullable` type of drawable

So now, one simple condition

```
if(icon!=null) {
   // Do your stuff here if it's not null
}else {
   // Do your overriding behaviour if it's null
}
```

But wait. What is the purpose of mentioning `@null` in XML if it still gives you the null as value and the same thing happens with not mentioning anything in xml.

So how to overcome this?

In order to overcome this, you need to set a global drawable for the icon in your styles.xml file like this

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
        <item name="icon">@drawable/some_drawable_that_does_exists</item>  
</style>
```

Notice: That is AppTheme

So we will have a common drawable for our view in app regardless you mention it in xml or not.

Even if you mention an icon in XML the mentioned icon will be used for rendering view.

Now if you mention @null on the view in XML your overriding condition mentioned in code will kicks in and you can do anything you want there.

Thanks.

Things to consider :

> 1. Name your custom attributes unique so that they can't collide with existing android attributes

Comment: i want that if no mention of the icon at all, then there will be default behaviour

Comment: Then you can use if(icon==null) condition and you don't have to use icon in styles.xml file i.e in AppTheme